# Wordpress Blog on Subfolder of Ruby on Rails App Hosted on Heroku

Tags: wordpress, heroku

I'm having trouble with this. I currently have a wordpress blog on my subdomain, like this: www.blog.websitename.com. However I want to move it to www.websitename.com/blog.

This is where the problem lies because at www.websitename.com, I have a ruby on rails app that's hosted on Heroku. I haven't been able to find any instructions on how to do this.

Would love anyone's suggestions!

Comment: Not sure why so many down votes - this is a really good question I've been looking for an answer to.

Answer (score 0):

In your database you have to serach `www.blog.websitename.com` and replace it with `www.websitename.com/blog`.

There is a nice script for this I often use for this purpose:

https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

Download it, upload it into your wordpress folder and call it via webrowser.

Maybe, if you have a .htaccess file in your wordpress folder, you have to adjust the path on 2 lines:

From:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

To:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```